# Error when connecting to AWS - IOT

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ssl, raspberry-pi, iot

I am using AWSIoTPythonSDK paho‐mqtt library and have problem connecting to AWS. Please help. Thanks!

```
#coding: utf-8

from AWSIoTPythonSDK.MQTTLib import AWSIoTMQTTClient
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep
from gpiozero import Buzzer, LED

bz = Buzzer(22)
led = LED(18)

# Custom MQTT message callback 
def custom_callback (client,userdata,message):
    print("Received a new message: ")
    print(message.payload)

    if message.payload == 'button_pressed':
        print("Doorbell pressed")
        bz.on()
        led.blink()
        sleep(1)
        bz.off()
        led.off()
        print("Done")

host="xxxxxxx.iot.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com"
rootCAPath="rootca.pem"
certificatePath="certificate.pem.crt"
privateKeyPath="private.pem.key"
my_rpi=AWSIoTMQTTClient("basicPubSub")
my_rpi.configureEndpoint(host,8883)
my_rpi.configureCredentials(rootCAPath,privateKeyPath,certificatePath)
my_rpi.configureOfflinePublishQueueing(-1)# Infinite offline Publish queueing
my_rpi.configureDrainingFrequency(2)# Draining: 2 Hz
my_rpi.configureConnectDisconnectTimeout(10)# 10 sec
my_rpi.configureMQTTOperationTimeout(5)# 5 sec
# Connect and subscribe to AWS IoT 
my_rpi.connect()
my_rpi.subscribe("sensors/button",1,custom_callback)

sleep(2)
```

This is the errors I received when I run the above code. I have checked that I have installed the necessary library. All AWS certs and keys are stored in the same folder as the above python code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Doorbell_Indoor.py", line 38, in <module>
    my_rpi.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/AWSIoTPythonSDK/MQTTLib.py", line 403, in connect
    return self._mqttCore.connect(keepAliveIntervalSecond)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/AWSIoTPythonSDK/core/protocol/mqttCore.py", line 290, in connect
    self._pahoClient.connect(self._host, self._port, keepAliveInterval)  # Throw exception...
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/AWSIoTPythonSDK/core/protocol/paho/client.py", line 655, in connect
    return self.reconnect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/AWSIoTPythonSDK/core/protocol/paho/client.py", line 777, in reconnect
    sock = socket.create_connection((self._host, self._port), source_address=(self._bind_address, 0))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 553, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Comment: This error is related to internet connection gateway, I fixed this error by changing default gateway to "8.8.8.8". You can try it.